# How to update data from localstorage if new data selected exists

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, local-storage

I am creating an ordering system which a user will select an item and add them to cart. I use local storage to save the items selected and get those items on the next page.

What I wanted to do now is to update the stored data if the user selected the same item.

For example
I have already stored

```
[{
 "id": "1",
 "name": "soap A",
 "quantity": "10",
 "price" : "50.00"
},
{
 "id": "2",
 "name": "soap X",
 "quantity": "10",
 "price" : "50.00"
}]
```

and the user again selected the the item with an `id` of `1` (which is `"soap A"`) and the quantity is `"15"`, my current result looks like this

```
[{
     "id": "1",
     "name": "soap A",
     "quantity": "10",
     "price" : "50.00"
    },
    {
     "id": "2",
     "name": "soap X",
     "quantity": "10",
     "price" : "50.00"
    },
    {
     "id": "1",
     "name": "soap A",
     "quantity": "15",
     "price" : "50.00"
    }]
```

What I wanted to do is to update if an object with the same ID exists on my local storage. it would look like this

```
[{
     "id": "1",
     "name": "soap A",
     "quantity": "25",
     "price" : "50.00"
    },
    {
     "id": "2",
     "name": "soap X",
     "quantity": "10",
     "price" : "50.00"
    }]
```

and here is my script for inserting to local storage.

```
var oldItems = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('itemsArray')) || [];
    var newItem = {
          'id' : $('#itemId').val(),
          'name': $('#productName').val(),
          'quantity': $('#quantity').val(),
          'price': $('#productPrice').val(),

      };
       oldItems.push(newItem);

localStorage.setItem('itemsArray', JSON.stringify(oldItems));
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to `find` a matching `id` in the current array, if it exists. If so, assign to that element - otherwise, push a new element.

```
const oldItems = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('itemsArray')) || [];
const idToUse = $('#itemId').val();
const existingItem = oldItems.find(({ id }) => id === idToUse);
if (existingItem) {
  Object.assign(existingItem, {
    'name': $('#productName').val(),
    'quantity': existingItem.quantity + $('#quantity').val(),
    'price': $('#productPrice').val(),
  })
} else {
  const newItem = {
    'id' : idToUse,
    'name': $('#productName').val(),
    'quantity': $('#quantity').val(),
    'price': $('#productPrice').val(),

  };
  oldItems.push(newItem);
}

localStorage.setItem('itemsArray', JSON.stringify(oldItems));
```

Comment: also, he can add the quantities if he wants to: `'quantity': existingItem.quantity + $('#quantity').val(),`

Comment: I guess it may be better to searchthe matching element by id instead of name as the id should be unique.

Comment: i tried replacing it using the id. and try to console.log existingItem but returns undefined.

Comment: @LionSmith If there is no `existingItem`, then you need to create a new item instead of trying to assign to `existingItem`, like the code in the answer does.

Comment: i already create a new item and try to add another item with the existing data.. but what happen is instead of updating the existing data it inserts. so what i did was i check the existingItem and it returns undefined..

Comment: @CertainPerformance i tried returning the id and the result was it only returns the 1st data from json array. now if i tried `return id===idToUse`  it returns undefined

Comment: @LionSmith If you want to identify a matching *id* that exists in `localStorage`, rather than a matching *name*, can you edit your question to clarify that? See edit

Comment: it works now... needed to clear cache sorry.. thanks