# How to add new json data to local storage without overwritting the previous data stored in localstorage

Tags: typescript, angular-material, angular-local-storage

[image: Project screenshot]Attached the screenshot of my project on how it currently looks like
My problem statement is: "You need to develop a single page web app (preferably, but not necessarily in AngularJS)."

The app should list and search for banks that are fetched from the API mentioned below. There should be a dropdown for cities (just put in 5 cities in there) and there is a search bar. As I type in the search area, the table should be dynamically filtered (client-side filtering). Search should be across all fields.

Here's the backend API to get a list of banks: https://vast-shore-74260.herokuapp.com/banks?city=MUMBAI

Essentials your applications should have: bank search screen which would show a list of banks user should be able to search by text for the banks, across all the fields (important: there would be no search button) pagination for the results of the search, the user should be able to select page size mark some banks as favourites. View banks that were marked as favourites (favourites should persist state event if the website is refreshed or reloaded) API calls should be cached

I have wrote the code and currently my project displays the JSON data in angular datatable with client-side filtering to search for the fields as well as pagination. Even implement a click event on mat favorite icon so that whenever the heart(favorite) icon is clicked the data in that row is stored in localstorage.

Problem is that whenever another row is clicked the previous data stored in localstorage is overwritten by the new data. I want to store the previous as well as new data.

```
</ service component that is bankhttpservice.ts 
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders, HttpClientModule } from 
'@angular/common/http';
import { HttpErrorResponse, HttpParams } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable'
import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/do';

@Injectable({
 providedIn: 'root'
})

export class BankhttpService {
   private baseUrl = "https://vast-shore-74260.herokuapp.com/banks";
   public myCity = "MUMBAI"

   constructor(private _http : HttpClient) {
       console.log('Bank http service called');
   }

   private handleError(err:HttpErrorResponse){
   console.log('Handle http error');
   console.log(err.message);
   return Observable.throw(err.message);
 }
 public getBankBranches(): any {
    let myResponse = this._http.get(this.baseUrl + '?city=' + 
      this.myCity);
    console.log(myResponse);
    return myResponse;
 }

 public getUserInfoFromLocalStorage = ()=>{
  return JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('fav'));
 }

 public setUserInfoInLocalStorage = (data)=>{
  localStorage.setItem('fav',JSON.stringify(data))
 }
 }
  />


 <  home.component.ts
 import { Component, OnInit, Inject, ViewChild,  ElementRef} from 
 '@angular/core';
 import { MatDialog, MatDialogRef, MAT_DIALOG_DATA } from 
 '@angular/material/dialog';
 import { MatSort, MatTableDataSource, MatPaginator, MatCheckboxModule} 
  from '@angular/material';
 import { BankhttpService } from '../bankhttp.service';

 export interface User {
    ifsc: string;
    bank_id: string;
    branch: string;
    address: string;
    city: string,
    district: string,
    state: string,
    bank_name: string
  }

  @Component({
   selector: 'app-home',
   templateUrl: './home.component.html',
   styleUrls: ['./home.component.css'],
   styles: [
     `
       table {
       width: 100%;
       }
       th.mat-sort-header-sorted {
       color: black;
       }
     `
     ]
   })
   export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {

   selectedRowIndex : any;
   displayedColumns: string[] = ['favorite','ifsc', 'bank_id', 'branch',  
   'city', 'district', 'state', 'bank_name'];
    dataSource;
    user;

   users: User[];

   @ViewChild('button') button: ElementRef; 
   @ViewChild(MatPaginator) paginator: MatPaginator;
   @ViewChild(MatSort) sort: MatSort;

   constructor(public bankHttpService : BankhttpService,  public dialog: 
    MatDialog) {
   console.log('Home component constructor is called');
   }

   ngOnInit() {
       console.log('Home component onIniti called');
       this.bankHttpService.getBankBranches()
        .subscribe((users: User[]) => {

       this.users = users;
       console.log(this.users)
       this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(users);
       console.log(this.dataSource)
       this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
       this.dataSource.sort = this.sort;
     });
     }

      applyFilter(filterValue: string) {
       filterValue = filterValue.trim(); // Remove whitespace
       filterValue = filterValue.toLowerCase(); // Datasource defaults to 
       lowercase matches
       this.dataSource.filter = filterValue;
       }

       toggle = true;
       status = 'Enable'; 
       selectedUser : any;

       activeSkill(element:any) {
         let user1 = [];
         this.selectedUser=element;
         console.log(element)
         this.bankHttpService.setUserInfoInLocalStorage(element)
         console.log(this.bankHttpService.getUserInfoFromLocalStorage())
       }
      }
      />


      </home.component.html
       <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon? 
        family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">

       <div class="example-header">
       <mat-form-field>
       <input matInput (keyup)="applyFilter($event.target.value)" 
       placeholder="Filter">
      </mat-form-field>
      </div>

     <div class="example-container">
     <table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" class="mat-elevation-z8" 
       matSort>

     <!-- ifsc Column -->
     <ng-container matColumnDef="favorite">
     <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> FAV </th>
     <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element;"> <button  
     (click)="activeSkill(element)" mat-icon-button>
     <mat-icon aria-label="Heart">favorite</mat-icon>
     </button>{{element.favorite}} </td>
     </ng-container>

    <!-- ifsc Column -->
    <ng-container matColumnDef="ifsc">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> IFSC </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.ifsc}} </td>
    </ng-container>

    <!-- bankid Column -->
    <ng-container matColumnDef="bank_id">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Bank Id </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.bank_id}} </td>
    </ng-container>

    <!-- branch Column -->
    <ng-container matColumnDef="branch">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Branch </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.branch}} </td>
    </ng-container>

    <!-- address Column -->
    <!-- <ng-container matColumnDef="address">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Website </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.address}} </td>
    </ng-container>-->

    <!-- <ng-container matColumnDef="action">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Action </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">
    <mat-icon (click)="editUser(element)">edit</mat-icon>
    </td>
    </ng-container>-->

    <ng-container matColumnDef="city">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> City </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.city}} </td>
    </ng-container>

   <ng-container matColumnDef="district">
   <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> District </th>
   <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.district}} </td>
   </ng-container>

   <ng-container matColumnDef="state">
   <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> State </th>
   <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.state}} </td>
   </ng-container>

   <ng-container matColumnDef="bank_name">
   <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Bank Name </th>
   <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.bank_name}} </td>
   </ng-container>

   <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
   <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></tr>
   </table>
   <mat-paginator [pageSizeOptions]="[5, 10, 25, 100]"></mat-paginator>
   </div>
   />
```

I want the local storage to display the previous data stored along with new data. Not just the new data and overwritting the old data

Comment: Can you please add a stackblitz demo for more understanding?

Comment: ok, for adding it to stackblitz i should add it to github repo right?

Comment: No need to create a GitHub repo. You can directly create a sample app using stackblitz that recreates your problem.

Comment: Suggestion - Instead of adding `data` to localStorage everytime, you push the new value in your data and then set it in localstorage

Comment: Check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52215389/how-to-update-data-from-localstorage-if-new-data-selected-exists)

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ofvnz3?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.module.ts    my code is not running in stackblitz due to errors, but i have got all the codes into this

Comment: You can simply merge the your existing localstorage data with new one.